# when to use technology like hadoop?

Tags: database-tuning, scalability

I understand that MySQL and others support large enough data for storing and retrieving. I am also aware of the open source projects such as hadoop and mapreduce etc.. (only their purpose and what they do).

EDIT:
when do you bring down the concept of hadoop , pig, mapreduce etc to your application?. Should we use these software in the beginning of the project itself or can it be induced at a later stage after the database is increased to large size?. Any link will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by scaling? Adding hardware? Changing RDBMS software?

Comment: it is software , i understand when hardware scaling is done. Am especially focused on scaling using technology like hadoop etc

Comment: You scale when the current software isn't meeting demand. Not sure if there is a better answer than that.

Comment: @JohnFx i would like to know that demand criteria. i have worked on small projects till date, so i have no idea on what that critical level would be

Comment: why down vote? leave a reason atleast !!

Comment: Hey sree, I did not downvote this question, but I can explain why others have: This question is too broad. If you update it to focus on some specific aspect of scaling it will be easier to answer. As it stands, this question is [not appropriate](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) for the Stack Exchange format. From the FAQ: "If you can imagine an [entire book](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_283155_ln?rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Adatabase+scalability&keywords=database+scalability) that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @NickChammas tnx for update, ll ask question in other way then....

Comment: scale I think that is when you can improve the performance, could be hardware, queries, configuration, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(While the question is broad, I hope that an equally broad answer will spark a useful discussion.)

Please see the accepted answer for [What is Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552488/509840.) at SO.

Google searches are a question that Hadoop can answer. Think about the characteristics of a large search engine:

1. Large amounts of data
2. Distributed data
3. Extreme parallelism

Scalability was mentioned in the comments: With Hadoop, it is not hard to throw additional (commodity) servers into the mix.

On to your question. If your project has a lot of SQL and von Neumann bottlenecks, then Hadoop makes little sense. If, however, your data is "Big Data," is less structured, and may be parallelized, then Hadoop will make more sense.